# Is there an error on page 100 of edition 1 of Principles of Computer System Design by Saltzer and Kaashoek?

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

This question is about a passage in the book `Principles of Computer System Design` by Jerome Saltzer and  M. Frans Kaashoek, 1st edition, from 2009, used in the MIT course 6.033 Computer Engineering.

There is a part of a chapter discussing how the file system in Unix version 6 is implemented. On page 100, it talks about links (aka synonyms, aliases), and in particular the operation UNLINK.

In a data structure called inode, you can keep track of the number of references there are to that inode, so that whenever you UNLINK a name to that inode the reference count goes down by one, and if it reaches zero, you can release the memory block used by inode and all the memory blocks it references.

However, there is a part which talks about cycles in the naming graph that is the directory hierarchy (we have a directed graph because of the links, we have a hierarchy because of the structure present in file names, which are path names composed of hierarchical components separated by forward slashes).

To start off the text defines pseudocode for a LINK operation:
`LINK("Mail/inbox'new-assignment", "assignment")` makes `assignment` a synonym for `Mail/inbox/new-assignment` in the directory `projects`, if the latter is the current working directory.

Here is the part of the text I am confused about:

> Using reference counts works only if there are no cycles in the naming
>   graph. To ensure that the unix naming network is a directed graph
>   without cycles, the unix file system forbids links to directories. To
>   see why cycles are avoided, consider a directory “a”, which contains a
>   directory “b”. If a program invokes link ("a/b/c", "a") in the
>   directory that contains “a”, then the system would return an error and
>   not perform the operation. If the system had performed this operation,
>   it would have created a cycle from “c” to “a” and would have increased
>   the reference count in the inode of “a” by one. If a program then
>   invokes unlink ("a"), the name “a” is removed, but the inode and the
>   blocks of “a” wouldn’t be removed because the reference count in the
>   inode of “a” is still positive (because of the link from “c” to “a”).
>   But once the name “a” would be removed, a user would no longer be able
>   to name the directory “a” and wouldn’t be able to remove it either. In
>   that case, the directory “a” and its subdirectories would be
>   disconnected from the naming graph, but the system would not remove it
>   because the reference count in the inode of “a” is still positive. It
>   is possible to detect this situation, for example by using garbage
>   collection, but it is expensive to do so. Instead, the designers chose
>   a simpler solution: don’t allow links to directories, which rules out
>   the possibility of cycles.

The questions I have here are:

1) if a program invokes a link("a/b/c", "a") in the directory that contains "a", and it succeeds how does this "create a cycle from "c" to "a"? After all we are linking the name "a" in the directory that contains "a" to "c". Is this an error in the text? Aren't we actually calling link("a", "a/b/c") to create a link from "a/b/c" to "a"?

The text says we increase the reference count on inode "a", and if we are indeed linking from "a/b/c" to "a" then I agree.

If we then unlink("a"), we will be removing the binding in the context of the directory that contains "a", but the inode that the name "a" was being bound to won't be removed, because "c" still has a reference to it.

The text says that directory "a" and its subdirectories would be disconnected from the naming graph, but the system would not remove it because the reference count of "a" is still positive.

2) The reason it is disconnected is the same reason "b" is disconnected, right? If we unlink "a", we are removing a reference to the inode that contains the naming scheme in which "b" is bound to its inode. Because we can't access "a", we can't access "b" and therefore we can't access "c" nor "a" from "c" anymore. So we have all these subdirectories disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, there is an error in the book, or the `link` operation it describes has been defined with arguments swapped from those of the POSIX system call `link` or the `ln` utility.

What the book *describes* is the operation

```
link("a", "a/b/c")
```

using the link(2) declared as `int link(const char *oldpath, const char *newpath);` or

```
ln a a/b/c
```

using the POSIX-standardized utility, executed when the current working directory is the parent of `a`.

Other than that the text is correct. It is well-known that reference counting alone cannot collect cycles. Rather than allowing for it, it is just easier to disallow hard-linking directories altogether. And for directories it is still possible to use symbolic links.

Answer (score 0):

The answer requires a deeper understanding of the function of the Unix file system than I can provide. Nevertheless I give it a try.

File `c` in directory `a/b` is aliased to a name `a` in the directory `a`.

(It seems that a name must be unique in a directory and there cannot exist a file `a` and a directory `a` in the same directory.)

Since the name `a` already exists, file `c` would be equated to the directory `a`. Accessing `a/b/c` would now access directory `a` and we could do `a/b/c/b/c...` which is a cycle.

`a`'s  link count would have been increased. Unlinking `a` would remove directory `a` from the inode, but because the link count is not zero, the storage of `a` would not be released.

(Attempt at explanation so far - let's read and comment.)

Comment: @evianpring, they both have an entry in the directory of the parent. They would be the same name, only differentiated by the `S_IFDIR` bit.

Comment: So, it seems there is an error in the book then. That link procedure should be link("a", "a/b/c")

Comment: @evianpring, the book seems correct: file `a/b/c` is equated to `a`.